# BackGradientStyle from bottom to top in MSChart?

Tags: c#, winforms, gradient, mschart

Is it possible to set `BackGradientStyle` from bottom to top using `MSChart`?
I found:

```
BackGradientStyle.TopBottom
```

but I want the reverse of this...

Comment: Can you show your code, how do you set the `BackColor` and `BackSecondaryColor` property?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I didn`t use BackSecondaryColor, but using it resolves my problem!

Comment: Glad I could help. You can accept your answer as accepted answer to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

> chart.BackColor = Color.White;
>       chart.BackSecondaryColor = Color.Red;
>         chart.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;

Answer (score 0):

There is no  bottom to top GradientStyle in MSchart but we can achieve this by alter color applied to chart.BackColor & chart.BackSecondaryColor.

Consider we have following code and which generate graph like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5VwF.jpg)

```
chart.BackColor = Color.White;
chart.BackSecondaryColor = Color.Green;
chart.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
```

but we want [this type of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GVR7.jpg) then we need to interchange color and  code will be

```
chart.BackColor = Color.Green;
chart.BackSecondaryColor = Color.White;
chart.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
```

If you want to apply Gradient to Series and want [graph like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHlcV.jpg)  then try bellow code

```
chart.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
chart.Series[0].BackSecondaryColor = Color.White;           
chart.Series[0].BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
```